# How to set timer on Android for a fragment to be removed?

Tags: android, timer, fragment

I would like to show a fragment and then remove the fragment after a certain time.

For loading I use FragmentTransaction replacing a FrameLayout. First I make the FrameLayout visible, replace it with the fragment and then I make use of the postDelayed() method:

```
contentFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TimetableDetailFragment timetableDetailFragment = new TimetableDetailFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.timetableContentFrame, timetableDetailFragment, "timetableDetailFragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
contentFrame.postDelayed(new Runnable(), 5000);
```

In the Runnable I try to remove this fragment and then update the visibility of the FrameLayout:

```
private class Runnable implements java.lang.Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("timetableDetailFragment") != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("timetableDetailFragment"));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            contentFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I create the fragment again I can see that the old fragment is still there before it is replaced with the new fragment.

Could there be a problem in trying to change the UI in a non-UI-thread? What is the typical way to achieve my goal?

Comment: you are running that runnable on the ui thread, if you werent there would be a RuntimeException? "Only the Thread that created the view...:"

Comment: Okay. So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: im not sure its a good idea to name your Class Runnable. also i would disable that custom animation just to see if this might be buggy somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

- Changed the name of Runnable class
- Added the following in parent fragment layout file:

  ```
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  ```
- Removed the custom animation

After that the problem was gone. Then I added the custom animation again and it still works.

I don't know what exactly solved the problem but now it works. Thank you, Daniel Bo!